# Google mobile friendly url testing tool giving 502 error

Tags: node.js, google-apis-explorer, google-search-console

I am using *google search console's URL testing tools API* for a while, and I am receiving a bunch of 502 bad gateway errors. I had submitted a quota increase request to bump up our default requests per day and described that we needed an increase in requests per minute (default is 60/minute). But unfortunately, google support has not responded yet. We are trying to call this API in parallel.
This is the error :

`Request failed with status code 502`

Could anyone help me understand this issue? I feel that we are exceeding the quota limits because 502 is usually associated with an issue while communicating with the upstream server.

Answer (score 0):

I have reported the issue in Google's public issue tracker. Please add your feedback there.. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194021199

It is broken and only works some times. The worse part is that it reports back as HTTP 200 in the google console without any errors so they probably have no idea that it is even broken.

Comment: Hey @andrew-fenn Did you ever get  a definitive reply from them? I also followed the conversation in https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/119990046/server-errors-with-the-mobile-friendly-test-api?hl=en but doesn't seems to be fixed. I am having this issue now.

Comment: Nope. I gave up. It seems to be something no team has the time to fix. My recommendation would be to simply not use it. It's worrying that the errors are hidden in GCP. Makes me wonder what else they're reporting as working in their cloud platform which isn't.